# How do I mock an acegi authenticate service for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spring-security

This my grails service class method:

```
class SomeService {

def authenticateService

def getUserName() {
    def cid = authenticateService.userDomain().customerid
    def uid = authenticateService.userDomain().userid
    def userDetails = User.findByCustomerIdAndUserId(cid, uid)

    return userDetails.lastName+", "+userDetails.firstName
}
```

How do I create a mock for the authenticateService provided by acegi security plugin for unit testing?

I've tried a unit test as :

```
class SomeServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
... 
...
def testGetUserName() {
    def service = new SomeService()

    def authService = mockFor(AuthenticateService)
    authService.demand.userDomain().customerid { -> return 111}
    authService.demand.userDomain().userid { -> return 222}
    service.authenticateService = authService.createMock()

    def uName = service.getUserName()

    asserNotNull uName
}
```

But, 
When I run the tests, it gives :

> Testsuite: SomeServiceTests
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 1.069 sec
>   Caused an ERROR
>   0
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>   at grails.test.DemandProxy.invokeMethod(GrailsMock.groovy:171)
>   at SomeServiceTests.testGetUserName(SomeServiceTests.groovy:230)

I'm unable to resolve the issue. Any help is appreciated, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines aren't making sense to me:

```
authService.demand.userDomain().customerid { -> return 111}
authService.demand.userDomain().userid { -> return 222}
```

Try something like this instead:

```
authService.demand.getUserDomain(2..2) { -> return [customerid:111, userid: 222] }
```